# Getting tables created in AWS DynamoDb using java code

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have created a table in dynamoDb in my AWS account called 'test'. I am trying to listAlltables  in my account by entering my credentials and using Java code:

```
  static void listAllTables() {
        static BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new  BasicAWSCredentials("AWSAccessKeyId", "AWSSecretKey");
        static DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCreds));


            TableCollection<ListTablesResult> tables = dynamoDB.listTables();
            Iterator<Table> iterator = tables.iterator();
            System.out.println("get tables names");

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Table table = iterator.next();
                System.out.println(table.getTableName());
            }

    }
```

I am not able to get the tables that I have created in the account. Can you please show me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: What region are you using? The SDK will default to the us-east-1 region so if you are using a different region you need to specify it.

Comment: I have changed the region in my account to us-east-1, then tested the code but it is also not working

Comment: I have used the setRegion function and it is working now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java SDK for AWS defaults to the us-east-1 region. You were likely not seeing any tables because you had none in the us-east-1 region. If your DynamoDB tables are in a different region you need to specify what region you want to have the SDK connect. Then your application will be able to see these tables in that other region.

Comment: yes. I have used this function and it worked          client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2))